# How to access Flow "export type" from different NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, flowtype

I am working on a scraper project with two separate directories, Dir A uses Flow to define types and contains scraper services while Dir B runs node-cron to call scraper services and upload to a database. However, when importing the scraper into Dir B I get this error:

```
export type {
       ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)


This error is due to me calling require('../scraper/src' in Dir A), where the code for ../scraper/src/index.js is: 

export type {
  AuthenticationType,
  ...
} from './types';
```

Where types define the scraper services' types.

I do have  "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types", "@babel/preset-flow" installed in both directories, and have Flow set up in both.

What mistakes am I making here? The end goal does be able to retrieve the scraper types in Dir B so I can run the actual scraping process.

Comment: Have you added `// @flow` to the top of the module calling the export?

Comment: @Brianzchen Yes, I added `// @flow` to both the code in Dir A and Dir B. More precisely, in Dir B I'm trying to access createScraper, which is exported here.

`// @flow
export {
  createScraper,
} from './factories';`

The issue is that I also export types in the file, and also in the createScraper setup.